# Hide and Show elements that are using Jquery UI Resizable

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently using Jquery UI to resize image elements, i can get it so i can resize multiple images, but i'd like to be able to toggle images visibility on/off.

I tried using CSS with display:none but the Jquery UI overwrites it, so can't think what else to try.

Is there anyway to toggle visibility of elements that have the resizable function applied to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI adds `ui-resizable` class to all resizable elements.

So, you can try something like this,

`$('.ui-resizable').toggle()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - i have tried it and it does work, but only if the elements are set to display on load - as soon as i use CSS to hide them or even JS, any toggle/show command stops working!